# OnChange event using React JS for drop down

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
     change: function(){
         return document.querySelector('#lang').value;
     },
     render: function(){
        return(
           <div>
               <select id="lang">
                  <option value="select" onChange={this.change}>Select</option>
                  <option value="Java" onChange={this.change}>Java</option>
                  <option value="C++" onChange={this.change}>C++</option>
               </select>
               <p></p>
               <p value={this.change}></p>
           </div>
        );
     }
});

React.render(<MySelect />, document.body);
```

The `onChange` event does not work.

Answer (score 446, accepted):

The change event is triggered on the `<select>` element, not the `<option>` element. However, that's not the only problem. The way you defined the `change` function won't cause a rerender of the component. It seems like you might not have fully grasped the concept of React yet, so maybe ["Thinking in React"](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/thinking-in-react.html) helps.

You have to store the selected value as state and update the state when the value changes. Updating the state will trigger a rerender of the component.

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
     getInitialState: function() {
         return {
             value: 'select'
         }
     },
     change: function(event){
         this.setState({value: event.target.value});
     },
     render: function(){
        return(
           <div>
               <select id="lang" onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>
                  <option value="select">Select</option>
                  <option value="Java">Java</option>
                  <option value="C++">C++</option>
               </select>
               <p></p>
               <p>{this.state.value}</p>
           </div>
        );
     }
});

React.render(<MySelect />, document.body);
```

Also note that `<p>` elements don't have a `value` attribute. React/JSX simply replicates the well-known HTML syntax, it doesn't introduce custom attributes (with the exception of `key` and `ref`). If you want the selected value to be the content of the `<p>` element then simply put inside of it, like you would do with any static content.

Learn more about event handling, state and form controls:

- http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html
- http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html

Comment: how can i get the inner text without the `value` being the same as the inner text?

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty: The usual: `event.target.textContent`

Comment: @FelixKling when I use textContent it print all the options inside de Select tag. What can I do to get only the selected ?

Comment: @Juan: Try `event.target.slectedOptions[0].label`.

Comment: @FelixKin: use event.persist() in onChange function as target will be null if this is not used.

Answer (score 92):

React Hooks (16.8+):

```
const Dropdown = ({
  options
}) => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0].value);
  return (
      <select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={e => setSelectedOption(e.target.value)}>
        {options.map(o => (
          <option key={o.value} value={o.value}>{o.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 45):

```
import React, { PureComponent, Fragment } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

class Select extends PureComponent {
  state = {
    options: [
      {
        name: 'Select…',
        value: null,
      },
      {
        name: 'A',
        value: 'a',
      },
      {
        name: 'B',
        value: 'b',
      },
      {
        name: 'C',
        value: 'c',
      },
    ],
    value: '?',
  };

  handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    const { options, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <Fragment>
        <select onChange={this.handleChange} value={value}>
          {options.map(item => (
            <option key={item.value} value={item.value}>
              {item.name}
            </option>
          ))}
        </select>
        <h1>Favorite letter: {value}</h1>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Select />, window.document.body);
```

Comment: very good.
            and you can see the result of change with this way
            <div>
                        <p>{this.state.value}</p>
            </div>

Answer (score 11):

```
  handleChange(value, selectOptionSetter) => {
     selectOptionSetter(value)
     // handle other stuff like persisting to store etc
   }

  const Dropdown = (props) => {
  const { options } = props;
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(options[0].value);
  return (
      <select
        value={selectedOption}
        onChange={e => handleChange(e.target.value, setSelectedOption)}>
        {options.map(o => (
          <option key={o.value} value={o.value}>{o.label}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 5):

Now you can use it like this

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  const [selectedItem, setSelectedItem] = useState("Counter")
  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedItem(e.target.value)
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <p>You have selected {selectedItem}</p>
      <select name='item-selected' value={selectedItem} onChange={handleChange}>
        <option value="Counter">Counter</option>
        <option value="useEffect">useEffect</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Most modern and recommended solution.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using select as inline to other component, then you can also use like given below.

```
<select onChange={(val) => this.handlePeriodChange(val.target.value)} className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle">
    <option value="TODAY">Today</option>
    <option value="THIS_WEEK" >This Week</option>
    <option value="THIS_MONTH">This Month</option>
    <option value="THIS_YEAR">This Year</option>
    <option selected value="LAST_AVAILABLE_DAY">Last Availabe NAV Day</option>
</select>
```

And on the component where select is used, define the function to handle onChange like below:

```
handlePeriodChange(selVal) {
    this.props.handlePeriodChange(selVal);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I'll add this here, in case it helps someone because this was the solution that helped me.

This is to get the SELECTED INDEX. Not for the value.
(Worked for me because my options list was a list of numbers)

```
const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState(0)
<select onChange={event => setSelectedOption(event.target.options.selectedIndex)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you Felix Kling, but his answer need a little change:

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
     return {
         value: 'select'
     }
 },
 change: function(event){
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 },
 render: function(){
    return(
       <div>
           <select id="lang" onChange={this.change.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}>
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="Java">Java</option>
              <option value="C++">C++</option>
           </select>
           <p></p>
           <p>{this.state.value}</p>
       </div>
    );
 }
});
React.render(<MySelect />, document.body);
```

Comment: Why are you adding `this.change.bind` in `onChange`?

Answer (score 0):

```
var MySelect = React.createClass({
getInitialState: function() {
```

```js
var MySelect = React.createClass({
 getInitialState: function() {
     return {
         value: 'select'
     }
 },
 change: function(event){
     event.persist(); //THE MAIN LINE THAT WILL SET THE VALUE
     this.setState({value: event.target.value});
 },
 render: function(){
    return(
       <div>
           <select id="lang" onChange={this.change.bind(this)} value={this.state.value}>
              <option value="select">Select</option>
              <option value="Java">Java</option>
              <option value="C++">C++</option>
           </select>
           <p></p>
           <p>{this.state.value}</p>
       </div>
    );
 }
});
React.render(<MySelect />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hooks and TypeScript, with the state living in the parent component:

```
import React from 'react';

interface Option {
  value: string;
  label: string;
}

interface DropdownProps {
  options: Option[];
  selectedOption: string;
  onOptionChange: (value: string) => void;
}

const Dropdown: React.FC<DropdownProps> = ({ options, selectedOption, onOptionChange }) => {
  return (
    <select
      value={selectedOption}
      onChange={(e) => onOptionChange(e.target.value)}
    >
      {options.map((o) => (
        <option key={o.value} value={o.value}>
          {o.label}
        </option>
      ))}
    </select>
  );
};

const Parent: React.FC = () => {
  const options: Option[] = [
    { value: 'option1', label: 'Option 1' },
    { value: 'option2', label: 'Option 2' },
    { value: 'option3', label: 'Option 3' },
  ];

  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState<string>(options[0].value);

  const handleOptionChange = (value: string) => {
    setSelectedOption(value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Dropdown options={options} selectedOption={selectedOption} onOptionChange={handleOptionChange} />
      <p>Your selected option: {selectedOption}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```