# How get the value from a select in flux

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have the following code on my render function using **jflux** framework.
So please anybody can give me an idea.

```
render: function(compile){  
        newCondominium: {province: ''}, 
        return compile(      
    <select name="provinceCondominium" id="selProvince" $$-value="newCondominium.province" class="form-control">
                                    <option disabled="true">--Select--</option>
                                    <option>Provincia 1</option>
                                    <option>Provinicia 2</option>
                                    <option>Provincia 3</option>
    )};
```

And I want to assign the new selected option to a variable.
How can I get the selected option?

Comment: See this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868135/2528440

Comment: possible duplicate of [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

Comment: (That doesn't look like ReactJS code ..., but the link @AndersNS suggested should help)

Comment: this is react but using _flux_ as framework