# React currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].value is failing in IE 10 after <select> onChange event

Tags: internet-explorer, reactjs

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/kj2b8dk7/4/

The following code is a simplified version of a problem I'm facing in a React 12.2 app using JSX, on IE 10. Specifically, the line

`var postData = rsvp.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].value;`

fails in IE. It works in Chrome and Firefox. First, why does this fail in IE10, and second, how can I adjust the code to make it work?

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {parsed: false};
    },
    _onRSVP: function(rsvp) {
        console.log(rsvp);
        var postData = rsvp.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].value;
        this.setState({parsed: true});
        alert(postData);
    },
    render: function() {
        var parsing = "parsing worked";
        return (
        <div>
        <select            
            onChange={this._onRSVP}>
            <option value="----">----</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <p>
        { this.state.parsed ?
        {parsing}
        : null}
        </p>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: Can you simplify this down to a jsbin/jsfiddle? There's a lot of code that I suspect isn't relevant to the issue.

Comment: @WiredPrairie just reduced quite a few lines. The key is really in the `render` function at the bottom, the rest are just things that aren't getting called, and so I've removed those and focused on what's important. Problem is that as far as I know I can't write JSX or use React 12.2 on either of those services.

Comment: I can't duplicate the issue with a simple example: https://jsfiddle.net/wiredprairie/69z2wepo/10379/. (Although I only have IE11 running in IE9 emulation mode).

Comment: @WiredPrairie thanks for your help! Got a lesson in debugging and updated the question appropriately. Any sense as to the solution now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change this line, `var postData = rsvp.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].value;` to:

```
var postData = rsvp.nativeEvent.srcElement.value;
```

DEMO: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kj2b8dk7/7/)

EDIT: Generally you could use this to get the target of the native DOM event:

```
function getTarget(e) {
    var targ;

    if (!e) {
        e = window.event;
    }

    if (e.target) {
        targ = e.target;
    } else if (e.srcElement) {
        targ = e.srcElement;
    }

    if (targ.nodeType == 3) { // defeat Safari bug
        targ = targ.parentNode;
    }

    return targ;
}
```

Then you could change the above line too:

```
var postData = getTarget(rsvp.nativeEvent).value;
```

[Source](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html#target)

Comment: thanks! One question - I looked for other ways and found this one - just using `event.target.value` per http://stackoverflow.com/a/28868135/2532070

Both appear to work - is your suggestion preferable for cross-browser performance?

Comment: `event` is a specific type from React, `SynteticEvent`, I think that the authors of react kept an eye on cross platform performance, so i would say "no". Both ways should do the same an all modern browsers (including IE9+).