# What is the proper way to get the value of a React <select> element?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, reactjs, html-select, internet-explorer-10

Say I have the following React element ([example fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/ypcrumble/ve88383c/3/)):

```
var Hello = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {parsed: false};
    },
    _parseEvent: function(event) {
        var parser1 = event.currentTarget.selectedOptions[0].value;
        var parser2 = event.target.value;
        var parser3 = event.nativeEvent.srcElement.value;
        if (parser1 && parser2 && parser3)
            this.setState({parsed: true});
    },
    render: function() {
        var parsing = "parsing worked";
        return (
        <div>
        <select            
            onChange={this._parseEvent}>
            <option value="----">----</option>
            <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="No">No</option>
        </select>
        <p>
        { this.state.parsed ?
        {parsing}
        : null}
        </p>
        </div>
        );
    }
});

React.render(<Hello name="World" />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

I'm using three ways of parsing the value of the `<select>` element. The first does not work on IE 10, and I know it's a bug per [my question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30856606/2532070). However, of the other two ways, `parser2` or `parser3`, which is the proper way to get the value of a `<select>` element in React? Why? Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use what you would use in a W3C compatible browser:

```
event.target.value
```

This is also agnostic to the type of the form control element.

Comment: @Felix_Kling thanks! Could you expand what you mean by W3C compatible browser? I'm googling "W3C <select> element" and "W3C compatible browser" but can't find the guidelines. Trying to figure out how to avoid making the same mistake in the future :).

Comment: [W3C](http://www.w3.org/) is the organization which creates the standards for web technologies, such as [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html), [HTML](http://www.w3.org/html/) or [DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/). W3C compatible just means that the browser fully implements the standard (notably, older IE versions do not, but React takes care of that).

Answer (score 1):

While the other answer works just fine, if you're looking for a React way, then this can be accomplished by using refs.

Assign a ref to the select:

```
<select onChange={this._parseEvent} ref="select">
    <option value="----">----</option>
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
/select>
```

Get the DOM node via ref:

```
var node = React.findDOMNode(this.refs.select)
```

Get the value via DOM node:

```
var value = node.value;
```

Here's an updated fiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/ve88383c/4/

Comment: I wouldn't call refs on inputs the react way.

Comment: @FakeRainBrigand There are many ways to do it using the utilities provided by React.  Refs is just one of those ways.  While perhaps it is not **the** react way, it is **a** react way.  I updated my answer with that grammar change.