# React js Invalid component element with using React.createClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

Now I'm **not** using **JSX** ( several reasons )

I'm able to work fine with **React.createElement**

e.g.

```
var ui =
    React.createElement('div', {},
        React.createElement('h1', {}, "Contacts"),
        React.createElement('ul', {},
            React.createElement('li', {},
                React.createElement('h2', {}, "James Nelson"),
                React.createElement('a', { href: 'mailto:james@json.com' }, 'james@json.com')
            ),
            React.createElement('li', {},
                React.createElement('h2', {}, "Joe Citizen"),
                React.createElement('a', { href: 'mailto:joe@example.com' }, 'joe@example.com')
            )
        )
    );

React.render(ui, document.getElementById('react-app'));
```

However, I started reading and seeing about the **createClass** but I'm getting this **error**

`react-with-addons.min.js:20302 Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: React.render(): Invalid component element. Instead of passing a component class, make sure to instantiate it by passing it to React.createElement.`

Here is my sample code in which I'm just trying to set a variable "x" to html and then use it in the **render**:  return **x**

What is wrong with this?

```
var x = "<div><select id='lang' onChange={this.change} value={this.state.value}>";
x = x + "<option value='select'>Select</option>";
x = x + "<option value='Java'>Java</option>";
x = x + "</select><p></p><p>{this.state.value}</p></div>";



var MySelect = React.createClass({

    change: function(event){
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    },
    render: function(){
            return(
                    x
                );
    }
});

React.render(MySelect, document.getElementById('react-main'));
```

Ultimately my goal is to create a dropdown in which onchange it will use react to show/hide other elements  ( textboxes etc...  )   Question with Answer Type ....

**UPDATE**

I do see various React in the project

This code someone wrote and I assume it "works"

```
SS.OpportunityDetailsGraph= React.createClass({displayName: "OpportunityDetailsGraph",

componentDidMount: function(){
    advisorDataManager.getOpportunityExceptionChart(this.props.opportunity.guid).done(this.renderChart);
},

renderChart:function(html){
    var content = $(this.getDOMNode()).find("#opportunity-details");
    content.html("").append(html).hide().fadeIn("slow");

},

render: function() {
    return (
    React.createElement("div", {className: "chart"}, 
                 React.createElement("div", {className: "ibox float-e-margins"}, 
                     React.createElement("div", {className: "ibox-content"}, 
                         React.createElement("div", {id: "opportunity-details"}, 
                             React.createElement(SS.Loader, null)
                         )
                     )
                 )
             )
        );
}
});
```

Comment: spot to bug... you are trying to render a string as html. why? like not only is that terrible concatenating strings like that. why not just write that exact html in the component return and use jsx? do you know how react works?

Comment: cannot use jsx in the project,  no I do not know enough how react works

Comment: I saw this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down     and so I started looking into the createClass  ,   i'm not using jsx ,  so I need to not having that dependency for now

Comment: @JosephAckerman that question you referenced is using JSX. The react community uses JSX. I think by not using it you are making things quite a bit more difficult for yourself since you won't find a lot of support from people not using it. Without JSX you will have to do a lot of manual stuff and I would suggest not using react.

Comment: Either use `React.createElement` or JSX. You can't wrangle HTML like that because React can't parse it.

Comment: See it less as a dependency and more as a valuable time-saving tool.

Comment: It's fine to use React without JSX, but you can't use strings of HTML or JSX instead of actual JSX. A render method needs to return a `ReactElement` -- you're just returning a string that contains JSX :/

Comment: ok, thanks for the advise