# No "onChange" event on materialize select element

Tags: javascript, dom, reactjs, materialize

I have this form component :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

export default class FooForm extends Component {
  updateFooSelection() {
    console.log('Something should be printed... but I see nothing :(');
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.initialiseWidgets();
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    this.initialiseWidgets();
  }

  initialiseWidgets() {
    Materialize.updateTextFields();
    $(this.refs.selectFoo).material_select();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
     $(this.refs.selectFoo).material_select('destroy');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <form>
        <select id="selFoo" ref="selectFoo" onChange={ this.updateFooSelection }>
          <option value="foo">Foo</option>
          <option value="bar">Bar</option>
        </select>
      </form>
    );
  }
};
```

However, the function `updateFooSelection` is *never* fired at all. When inspecting the DOM, there doesn't seem to be any `onchange` attribute or anything like that. I tried understanding the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html), however there is no example for such element.

How can I get a change event for a select element with Materialize in React?

How come the `onChange` event is never fired on this element?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

Comment: No! The event is **not** triggered at all! It's not about having a reactive SELECT element.

Comment: Are you using es6? Can you show a bit more of your component?

Comment: @Donal this link has nothing to do with my question, it addresses issues with keystrokes and INPUT elements. My question is about selection changes that are not being triggered *at all*.

Comment: In *updateFooSelection()* you miss a double quote at the end of the console.log, or it is a typo?

Comment: @MarioAlexandroSantini yes, I'll fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You won't find an `onchange` attribute or `change` handler on the rendered DOM element, because React uses [its own event delegation system](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/interactivity-and-dynamic-uis.html#under-the-hood-autobinding-and-event-delegation).

Answer (score 6):

[This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3667) explains why.

Basically, the `ònChange` props will simply no work, and `.on('change', ...` needs to be used instead.

```
initialiseWidgets() {
  Materialize.updateTextFields();
  $(this.refs.selectFoo).on('change', function () {
     console.log('yay!');
  }).material_select();
}
```