# onChange event select in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to get the value of an option inside my select in React.js but somehow e.value is always undefined.

This is the code:

```
<Col md={4} className="col-padding-left">
                            <Input onChange={this.filterProducts} type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect">
                                <option name='default'>Default</option>
                                <option name='price' value='desc'>Price (High-Low)</option>
                                <option name='price' value='asc'>Price (Low-High)</option>
                                <option name='addedAt' value='desc'>Added At (First-Last)</option>
                                <option name='addedAt' value='asc' >Added At (Last-First)</option>
                                <option name='name' value='desc'>Name (A-Z)</option>
                                <option name='name' value='asc'>Name (Z-A)</option>
                            </Input>
                        </Col>
```

With the following function `filterProducts`:

```
filterProducts(e){
            console.log(e.value); 
      }
```

Comment: Which lib are u using for Select?

Comment: It is `e.target.value`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<Col md={4} className="col-padding-left">
                        <Input onChange={this.filterProducts.bind(this)} type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect">
                            <option name='default'>Default</option>
                            <option name='price' value='desc'>Price (High-Low)</option>
                            <option name='price' value='asc'>Price (Low-High)</option>
                            <option name='addedAt' value='desc'>Added At (First-Last)</option>
                            <option name='addedAt' value='asc' >Added At (Last-First)</option>
                            <option name='name' value='desc'>Name (A-Z)</option>
                            <option name='name' value='asc'>Name (Z-A)</option>
                        </Input>
                    </Col>


filterProducts = (e) => {
        console.log(e.target.value); 
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `e.target.value`

See this question: [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

Answer (score 0):

First, check if you have `e`. If so, try `e.target.value`.

Answer (score 0):

The `event` object doesn't hold a `value` property.
In order to access the `value` attribute of element you need to use `event.target.value` when `target` is the element that triggered this event.

Running example:

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: ['john', 'jane', 'greg']
    };
  }

  onSelect = e => {
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }

  render() {
    const{items} = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <select onChange={this.onSelect}>
        {
          items.map(item => {
            return (<option value={item}>{item}</option>)
          })
        }
        </select>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your request, it's my solution:

```
<Col md={4} className="col-padding-left">
                            <Input onChange={this.filterProducts} type="select" name="select" id="exampleSelect">
                                <option name='default'>Default</option>
                                <option name='price' value='desc'>Price (High-Low)</option>
                                <option name='price' value='asc'>Price (Low-High)</option>
                                <option name='addedAt' value='desc'>Added At (First-Last)</option>
                                <option name='addedAt' value='asc' >Added At (Last-First)</option>
                                <option name='name' value='desc'>Name (A-Z)</option>
                                <option name='name' value='asc'>Name (Z-A)</option>
                            </Input>
                        </Col>
```

The function for could be:

```
filterProducts(e){
    // e.target.id identified the unique element in DOM 
    // in example when 'exampleSelect' make a change (onChange) event
    if(e.target.id === 'exampleSelect'){  
            console.log("Value for exampleSelect: " + e.target.value);   
    }
    // if you have another html input select add here another 'if'
    // with a diferent id. ex.
    if(e.target.id === 'fruitSelect'){  
            console.log("Value for fruit: " + e.target.value);   
    }
    ...
}
```

**¡Ey!**, don't forget to bind the function, in the React constructor:

```
this.filterProducts = this.filterProducts.bind(this);
```