# Reactjs <select> not triggering onChange

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, select

I'building a simple stateless component using the `<select>` tag.

The `onChange` event is not being called every time I select an option. Once in a while it is called (after a random number of item selects).

```
class TestList extends Component {

    handleSelectListChange = event => {
        console.log("CLICKED " + event.target.value);
    };

    getList = () => {
        let options = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            options.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{"ITEM " + i}</option>);
        }

        return (
            <select size={20} onChange={this.handleSelectListChange}>
                {options}
            </select>
        );
    };

    render = () => {
        let list = this.getList();

        return (
            <div>{list}</div>
        );
    };
}

export default TestList;
```

Why does my onChange is not being fired on every item click ?

Comment: hope it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down

Comment: @Snehal, the problem is not related to state change (I'm aware of this). The problem is that the onChange event is not being called...

Comment: I tried the code myself and its works ? and the event is called each time I select any option ?

Comment: works fine when I tested it, maybe you are getting another error. Did you check console?

Comment: have you tried to bind the handleSelectListChange to this?
in the constructor: 
    this.handleSelectListChange = this.handleSelectListChange.bind(this);

Comment: In jSFiddle the same code works: https://jsfiddle.net/57hofydw/

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo, indeed work. I will check the context of the component inside my project...

Comment: Ensure you are not clicking near the select border because it's not clickable :)

Comment: @PaoloDell'Aguzzo this is not the problem. Continue not working on my environment, even with a minimal code...

Comment: @Mendes Strange, if it can depend on your environment is difficult for us to help you. But..! Try to change your handleSelectListChange, use a normal function and not the arrow one. Bind the function and try if it works (you could have problem with configuration ?!). After that use the react developer tool for chrome and inspect what's going on when you select an element.

Comment: I've done all of that already....

Answer (score 0):

change the code from

```
 <select size={20} onChange={this.handleSelectListChange}>
```

to

```
<select size={20} onChange={this.handleSelectListChange.bind(this)}>
```

Comment: No need to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It Works Correctly.

```
import { Component } from "react";

import React from "react";

class TestList extends Component {

handleSelectListChange = event => {
    console.log("CLICKED " + event.target.value);
};

getList = () => {
    let options = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        options.push(<option key={i} value={i}>{"ITEM " + i}</option>);
    }

    return (
        <select size={20} onChange={this.handleSelectListChange}>
            {options}
        </select>
    );
};

render = () => {
    let list = this.getList();

    return (
        <div>{list}</div>
    );
};
}
export default TestList;
```

[image]