# How to alert out the value of an option box in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to get the values of the option boxes. Here's the sample code I wrote. I am trying to populate the option boxes from arrays.  I can tell you details if needed for the solution. Thank you for your help in advance!

```
import React from 'react';

class Scooters extends React.Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    cat_brand: ['Honda', 'Peugeot', 'Yamaha'],
    cat_cc: ['50cc', '125cc', '150cc', '250cc', '300cc'],
    cat_price: ['20-70 €', '80-120 €', '130-160 €']
  }

  btnClick() {
    alert('Button has been clicked...');
    {/* I would like to alert here the selected options of the boxes. */}

  }

  render() {
    let Brand_categoryOptions = this.props.cat_brand.map(categoryBrand => {
      return <option key={categoryBrand} value={categoryBrand}>{categoryBrand}</option>
    });
    let Cc_categoryOptions = this.props.cat_cc.map(categoryCc => {
      return <option key={categoryCc} value={categoryCc}>{categoryCc}</option>
    });
    let Price_categoryOptions = this.props.cat_price.map(categoryPrice => {
      return <option key={categoryPrice} value={categoryPrice}>{categoryPrice}</option>
    });

  return (

    <div>
      <div className="container-fluid content">
        <h2 className="text-center mt-2">Choose from our Scooters</h2>

        <br></br>

      <form>
      <div class="container col-lg-4 mt-5">
        <table class="table table-bordered">

        <tr><th>Specifications</th> <th>Set the parameters</th></tr>
        <tr><td>Scooter Brand</td> <td><select ref="cat_brand">{Brand_categoryOptions}</select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Engine CC</td>     <td><select ref="cat_cc">{Cc_categoryOptions}</select></td></tr>
        <tr><td>Unit Price</td>    <td><select ref="cat_price">{Price_categoryOptions}</select></td></tr>
        <tr><th>Action</th> <th><button  onClick={this.btnClick}>Search</button></th></tr>

        </table>
      </div>
      </form>


      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
};

export default Scooters;
```

Comment: have a look at this ans  -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add event handler function to select element and store the value in state. Also don’t forget to bind your btnClick function in constructor or use arrow function instead

Below code would work

```
  dropDownChange = e => {
       this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
  }

  btnClick = () => {
      alert('Option selected ', this.state.value);
  }
  <select ref="cat_price" onChange={this.dropDownChange} value={this.state.value}>{Price_categoryOptions}</select>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is just working like charm! A quick fix: alert('Option selected ' + this.state.value); and I had to add:   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      value: ""
          };
  }

Comment: @Alex94 NP. Kindly do upvote as well as you have accepted the answer :)

Comment: I cannot upvote, the system does not allow me to. MAybe I am too new here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I added an onChange handler on the form which takes the change event, and sets the components state respectively (the state is initialized with a value from your default props, so that if you selected nothing and click it has the default values).

It gets the name attribute on the select element and the value from the event target. And on submit you prevent the default behavior which is the submit, so you can do whatever you want with your data.

```
class Scooters extends React.Component {

  static defaultProps = {
    cat_brand: ['Honda', 'Peugeot', 'Yamaha'],
    cat_cc: ['50cc', '125cc', '150cc', '250cc', '300cc'],
    cat_price: ['20-70 €', '80-120 €', '130-160 €']
  }

  state = {
    cat_brand: this.props.cat_brand[0],
    cat_cc: this.props.cat_cc[0],
    cat_price: this.props.cat_price[0],
  }

  onChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    this.setState({ [name]: value })
  }

  btnClick = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {

    let Brand_categoryOptions = this.props.cat_brand.map(categoryBrand => (<option key={categoryBrand} value={categoryBrand}>{categoryBrand}</option>));
    let Cc_categoryOptions = this.props.cat_cc.map(categoryCc => (<option key={categoryCc} value={categoryCc}>{categoryCc}</option>));
    let Price_categoryOptions = this.props.cat_price.map(categoryPrice => (<option key={categoryPrice} value={categoryPrice}>{categoryPrice}</option>));

    return (

      <div>
        <div className="container-fluid content">
          <h2 className="text-center mt-2">Choose from our Scooters</h2>
          <br></br>
          <form onChange={this.onChange}>
            <div className="container col-lg-4 mt-5">
              <table className="table table-bordered">
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Specifications</th>
                    <th>Set the parameters</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Scooter Brand</td>
                    <td>
                      <select name="cat_brand" ref="cat_brand">{Brand_categoryOptions}</select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Engine CC</td>
                    <td>
                      <select name="cat_cc" ref="cat_cc">{Cc_categoryOptions}</select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td>Unit Price</td>
                    <td>
                      <select name="cat_price" ref="cat_price">{Price_categoryOptions}</select>
                    </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Action</th>
                    <th>
                      <button onClick={this.btnClick}>Search</button>
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

Comment: Hi, this looks fine for me, I'm gonna give it a try. Thank you so much!