# Handling events on dynamically created <select> dropdown options

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a function which returns a dropdown.  This function gets called from some parent, where the parent passes in props including a state key, array, and onChange.  The dropdown is created dynamically from the items in the array.  What I want to happen is, when an option in the dropdown is selected, the parents passed in state key gets updated to the value of whatever was selected.  Currently, I am trying to do this by setting an onClick handler per , which doesn't work.  Instead, I am met with either no or undefined values (described more below).

Example flow:

- Parent passes in aStateKey (actual state key), an array to be used as dropdown values, and an onChange function to be used to update aStateKey
- The dropdown menu is created from the passed inarray
- A dropdown item is selected
- aStateKey (which was passed in as a prop) gets updated via the passed in onChange function.

I understand that the traditional method is to give  and onChange handler, but I am having troubles working out how to get the desired described above.

**Parent**

```
state = { aStateKey: "" };

someArray = ["test", "another test"];

updateField = (name, value) => {
        console.log("Updating field: " + name + " with value: " + value);
    
}

return(
    <div>
        <CreateDropdown name="aStateKey" items={this.someArray} onChange={this.updateField} />
    </div>
);
```

**CreateDropdown**

```
function CreateDropdown(props) {
    const handleClick = event => {
        console.log("changed name:" + event.name + "changed value: " + event.value);
        props.onChange(event.name, event.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <select>
                {props.items.map(field => (
                    <option key={field} value={field} name={props.name} onClick={handleClick}>
                        {field}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**Console log**

Shows nothing!  However, if I move the onClick from `<option>` to `<select>`, i.e.

```
return (
        <div>
            <select onChange={handleClick}>
                {props.items.map(field => (
                    <option key={field} value={field} name={props.name}>
                        {field}
                    </option>
                ))}
            </select>
        </div>
    );
```

The console shows:

> Updating field: undefined with value: undefined.
>
> changed name:undefinedchanged value: undefined

How can I achieve my desired behavior?

Comment: Duplicate of [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down). Please do more research before posting a question. You need to pass a value prop to the select element. and you need to access that value in the handler. You need an onChange as well on the select

Comment: @JohnRuddell I believe this question is not a duplicate because the question you've linked is a general question about OnChange listeners, where mine is more specific and even includes code for the "right" way to implement these listeners as state in the question you've linked.

Comment: Well you aren't setting up your listeners correctly / using the values correctly. I would give a that other questions accepted answer a shot :)

Comment: @JohnRuddell Fair -- the answer to the question you linked is also useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE #1**

Inside `handleClick`, you are using `event.name` and `event.value` to get the target values you want.

instead use `event.target.name` and `event.target.value`

---

Try using `onChange` instead of `onClick` in your `select` element.

It belongs to `select` not `option` elements.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however I have tried that and posted the resulting behavior in my question.

Comment: You are using `onClick` event handler, as I suggested, you should use `onChange` instead.

Comment: I'll update my post to say `onChange`.  The behavior is the same regardless.

Comment: theres a few issues, main one is there is no `value` passed to the select component. Its a duplicate of the link posted in the close vote

Comment: Please check UPDATE #1 in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

your target form this event is select and use onChange and here the updated function you need:

```
function CreateDropdown(props) {

  return (
     <div>
        <select name={props.name} onChange={e => 
          props.onChange(e.target.name, e.target.value);}>
            {props.items.map(field => (
                <option key={field} value={field} 
                    {field}
                </option>
            ))}
        </select>
     </div>
   );
}
```