# How to setState with <select> after component has mounted and options have been generated?

Tags: reactjs

I have a problem where state object needs to be set after options have been generated and not only when `onChange` is triggered upon selection change. I have the following state:

```
this.state = {
   trailers: [],
   createTrailer: "",

}
```

This populates based on what is selected in my `<select>` element with an `onChange` handler:

```
handleStateChange = (event) => {
    this.setState({[event.target.name]: event.target.value})
}
```

It works fine, **however**,the  options get populated from a GET request in `componentDidMount()` and what gets selected by default when it populates does not change the state. Thus, the `createTrailer` state stays blank until I actually select something.

How can I populate my state with the default option in a scenario where I don't change my selection but leave the default one? Because at the moment if I leave it obviously that does not work with my form submission as a blank value gets submitted.

```
<b><label>Choose:</label></b>

<select className="form-control" name="createTrailer" onChange={this.handleStateChange} id="trailerSelect">
    {
      trailers.length
          ? trailers.map(trailer => <option key={trailer._id} value={trailer._id}>{trailer.trailerNum}</option>)
          : null
    }
</select>
```

**EDIT**: Duplicate question does not answer my question, it explains how to handle state changes with `<select>` and I have done all of that correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

Comment: @imjared I've read it, it's not.

Comment: you can call `setState` after the request finished with the first item in the result

Comment: Thanks @DoronBrikman it worked. If you post as an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure If i understand your question but you can:

- create function like this:
  `updateState = (name, value) => this.setState({[name]: value})`
- use this function in handleChange
- use this function also after the GET request resolves, something like
  `.then(response => this.updateState(response.x, response.y))`

Comment: No need for the first bullet point I think as I have that sorted. Last point is the answer, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, I don't know your full requirements. But here's how I would do something like that using hooks.

The `useEffect()` hook in this situation is working very similar to the `componentDidMount()` method.

If you're not familiar with React Hooks, I encourage you to give it a try.

Nevertheless, there is the same component as a class, in the second snippet.

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html

**SNIPPET WITH HOOKS**

```js
const trailersArray = ['Trailer A', 'Trailer B', 'Trailer C'];

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(trailersArray),1000);
  });
}


function App() {

  const [loading, setLoading] = React.useState(true);
  const [trailers, setTrailers] = React.useState([]);
  const [selectedTrailer, setSelectedTrailer] = React.useState(null);
  
  React.useEffect(()=>{
    mockAPI()
    .then((data)=>{
      setTrailers(data);
      setSelectedTrailer('Trailer A');
      setLoading(false);
    });
  },[]);
  
  const trailerItems = trailers.length ?
    trailers.map((item) => 
      <div
        onClick={()=>setSelectedTrailer(item)}
        className={item === selectedTrailer ? 'item selected' : 'item'}
      >
        {item}
      </div>
    ) 
  : null;

  return(
    <div className="list">
      {loading ? 
        <div>Loading...</div>
        : <React.Fragment>
            <div>Click to select</div>
            {trailerItems}
          </React.Fragment>
      }
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.list {
  width: 150px;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

**SNIPPET WITH CLASS**

```js
const trailersArray = ['Trailer A', 'Trailer B', 'Trailer C'];

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>resolve(trailersArray),1000);
  });
}

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      loading: true,
      trailers: [],
      selectedTrailer: null
    };
  }
  
  componentDidMount() {
    mockAPI()
    .then((data) => {
      this.setState({
        trailers: data,
        selectedTrailer: data[0],
        loading: false
      });
    });
  }
  
  render() {
  
    const trailerItems = this.state.trailers.length ?
      this.state.trailers.map((item) => 
        <div
          onClick={()=>this.setState({selectedTrailer: item})}
          className={item === this.state.selectedTrailer ? 'item selected' : 'item'}
        >
          {item}
        </div>
      ) 
    : null;
    
    return(
      <div className="list">
        {this.state.loading ? 
          <div>Loading...</div>
          : <React.Fragment>
              <div>Click to select</div>
              {trailerItems}
            </React.Fragment>
        }
      </div>
    );
  
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.list {
  width: 150px;
}

.item {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"/>
```

Comment: Just started to learn React, so haven't had the time to look at hooks yet. I will do in the future. Thanks though!

Comment: Nice. I do encourage you to learn the basics with "traditional" stateful classes components and lifecycle methods before moving into hooks. I'll try to add an example with classes to my answer.

Comment: I've added the class example. Hope that helps.