# How do I get value of mapped options onChange of select dropdown in react?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, reactjs, object

I have a list of `option`, I'm getting from the API. I'm using `.map()` and When I change the option I want the specific option object so I can store that inside of redux store.

```
            <select
              onChange={() => handleChange()}
              className="pl-2 bg-white font-medium border-none"
            >
              {outlets.map((outletItem) => (
                <option key={outletItem.outlet_id} value={outletItem.outlet_id}>
                  {outletItem.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
```

Here, `outlets` is an array from the API. I want the specific value of the array when I make a change. 
handleChange()

```
  const handleChange = () => {
    dispatch(addSelectedOutlet(outlets));
  };
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [OnChange event using React JS for drop down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28868071/onchange-event-using-react-js-for-drop-down)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to catch the value of onChange

```
onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
```

then

```
const handleChange = (e) => {
  console.log(e.target.value)
};
```

Comment: e.target.value is the only way, cause I passed the outletItem in value and I'm getting
selectedOutlet(pin):{} => '[object Object]'