# ReactJS - having the second dropdown box data depend on the first selected dropdown box data?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a state variable that looks rather complex.. like this:

```
[
    {
        objName: nameOne,
        objData: [
            {
                colName: [ colData ]
            },
            {
                colName: [ colData]
            }
        ]
    },
...
]
```

For the first dropdown box, the data displayed is all the `objName`s. And that works fine. But the second should display all the `colName`s based on which ever `objName` was selected. My problem is that the size of this is dynamic.

I basically just want to take what ever was selected and query the state variable like a dictionary and display all the column names. Is this possible?

I already have the code built out for the `<select>`s. But I just dont know how to handle this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to save the current selection (in the first dropdown) in the state of the component. I think this answer is useful here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28868135/1326264

Then you can use this saved selection to populate the second dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to filter based on the first dropdown's value that is selected. So your second dropdown's object should have a value which matches something from the first dropdown's value. For example, lets you have a list of Countries and a list of cities.

```
const country = ['USA','UK', 'India']
const cities = [{name:'Los Angeles', country:'USA'},{name:'California', country:'USA'},{name:'London', country:'UK'}, {name:'Delhi', country:'India'}]
```

Then you can update your `cities` state variable whenever the `country` state variable changes by putting in a useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
    setCities(cities.filter(city => city.country === country))
},[country])
```